# Chrome extension don't create group after create tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension, I create multiple tabs and want to group them. Tabs are created successfully, but grouping doesn't work. There are no errors, the function simply doesn't execute

Code:

```js
const listProjects = ["one", "two"] 
var listUrls = listProjects.map(url => `https://example/${url}`);
listUrls.map(url => chrome.tabs.create({ url }));

var targetUrl = "https://example/*";
let queryOptions = { url: targetUrl };
const tab = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
var tabsIds = tab.map(tab => tab.id)
chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: tabsIds })
```

Individually, this code works, but not after chrome.tabs.create.

```js
var targetUrl = "https://example/*";
let queryOptions = { url: targetUrl };
const tab = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
var tabsIds = tab.map(tab => tab.id)
chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: tabsIds })
```

Comment: You need to wait for the tabs to be actually created by adding `await Promise.all(` before listUrls.map.

Comment: It didn't help (

Comment: Well, I guess the tabs don't have a URL immediately after creating, so just remove chrome.tabs.query and use the result of awaiting i.e. const tabs = await Promise.all(listUrls.map..........

Answer (score 0):

it's work

```js
const tabIds = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < tabUrls.length; i++) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: tabUrls[i], active: false }, function(newTab) {
      // Adding the identifier to the array
      tabIds.push(newTab.id);
      // Checking if all tabs are created
      if (tabIds.length === tabUrls.length) {
        // Grouping all tabs
        chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: tabIds });
      }
    });
  }
```